# Cakephp 3 Default Model not loaded in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a controller name `CodeBridgeController` and have a model table name `CodeBridgeTable`.
When I call CodeBridge table in action like following:

```
$this->CodeBridge->find('all')->toArray();
```

This generate `Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
File D:\php\htdocs\cake3\erp\src\Controller\CodeBridgeController.php
Line: 25`
I think this is silly matter but i could not find any wrong in the code why table is not loaded in this context.
When i call this way it works.

`$codeBridgeTable = TableRegistry::get('CodeBridge');
 $results = $codeBridgeTable->find('all')->hydrate(false)->toArray();`

What may create the problem, expert suggestion needed.

Comment: use inflector class to know conventionally correct controller/table class. http://sandbox3.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector

Comment: Start with debugging what `$this->CodeBridge` actually is (`debug($this->CodeBridge)`). Given that the error message says that it's a non-object, I'd assume that the table-instance auto loading mechanism isn't even reached, and/or that there already is something assigned to `$this->CodeBridge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found where the problem lies.
In controller action, I generating a url like following:
`Router::url(array('controller' =>'codebridge','action'=>'edit'));` which generate url `/cake3/erp/codebridge/edit`

After changing the controller name in camel case `Router::url(array('controller' =>'CodeBridge','action'=>'edit'));` which generate url '/cake3/erp/code-bridge/edit`

This solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this, just load the model prior to trying to use it:

```
$this->loadModel("CodeBridge");
$this->CodeBridge->find('all')->toArray();
```

Comment: This is cargo cult programming. When something should work but doesn't, it's better to find out why it's not working than to just use a workaround. Following this advice would almost certainly lead to other problems related to the underlying issue.