# Implement tables with error underscores: Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, camelcasing, cakephp-3.8

when I implement a table with the name example_a call:

- model/entity: ExampleA.php
- model/table: ExampleATable.php
- controller: ExampleAController.php
- Template/ExampleA: index.ctp

gives me the following error:

Notice (1024): Undefined property: ExampleAController :: $ ExampleA in C: Program Files …

Fatal error: Call to a member function find () on boolean

to print the list of objects in the controller implement a function:

```
 public function index ()
 {
     $This->set('examples',$this->ExampleA->find('all'));
 }
```

I specify that this table has no relationship whatsoever with other tables

if instead I do the same thing implementing a table without underscore it works

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009972/1309690

Comment: Did you already try to print something to your view without query? Does it succeed print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that you have deviated from the [CakePHP conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/intro/conventions.html), which is fine, but means you need to do some extra work.

The first thing to do is tell the framework what your Table and Entity classes are called. In your `ExampleATable.php` file in the `initialize()` method, you need to set the table, entity and other things.

```php
<?php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('example_a');
    $this->setAlias('ExampleA');
    $this->setEntityClass(\App\Model\Entity\ExampleA::class);
    //etc
```

Secondly, in your controller, we'll need to manually load the Table class, as it doesn't match the controller.

```php
// Get or create a table instance
$ExampleATable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('ExampleA');

// Use the table instance to query
$query = $ExampleATable->find();
```

Comment: I had read the CakePHP conventions. I thought I respected them, maybe the only one is the model/entity name. To respect them as I should have done?